# Error 2100: Detection error on HDD0 (Main HDD) - Lenovo Twist

Tags: windows-8, hard-drive, boot, bios

I have a Lenovo Twist (S230u).  When I boot it up, it shows the LENOVO logo, then under that it says ''To interrupt normal startup, press Enter''.  Then it says ''2100: Detection error on HDD0 (Main HDD)''.  How can I fix this?  I tried taking out the HDD and putting it back in.  There are usually three items in the boot menu: ATA HDD0 (Hitachi), ATA HDD2 (Samsung) and PCI LAN.  But sometimes the first one goes away and there is a 2100 error.  Even when there is no error, it still does not boot to windows, just goes to the Boot Menu.

Comment: "Google is your friend" -- there is a lot of information available about this.  Bottom line -- if it runs again, back up your data, as it may be failing. Then read this: http://forums.lenovo.com/t5/X-Series-ThinkPad-Laptops/STRONG-SUGGESTION-about-firmware-fixing-some-Seagate-failure-on/m-p/92128 and get in touch with Lenovo (or try their forums.)  I'm kinda new here, but I believe that there's an emphasis on at least trying to research your question for yourself, first.

Comment: I am having this problem as well; but I wanted to add here that every report of this issue I've seen does not indicate a problem with the drive itself (my own issue is on a brand new drive with no SMART errors, behaves well in other machines even when used for booting, detected by OS's via boot CDs, *and other drives in this machine yield the error as well*). The issue is also exclusive to SSDs on Lenovo machines (Samsung 840 EVO + T520 for me).